# How to overwrite partition in BigQuery using scheduled query that runs every hour?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in the BigQuery, the table is partitioned by day. And I need to setup a scheduled query, that will run every hour, get all today's records, aggregate them, and write truncate the results to a destination table to today's partition. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries
where it's described how to use the bq command line, or Java/Python to build and schedule queries. In the same time you can choose the destination table to be the current day's partition using the $ sign notation for daily partitions (for instance today's partition can be described as `table_name$20201221`).

Depending on your use-case (e.g. what kind of aggregations you want to do), it might be also worthwhile having a look at materialised views

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro

Of course there are also other ways to achieve what you want to do, if you're using a scheduler in particular, but I'm guessing that your question is mostly referring to doing it simply by using BigQuery.